# How to solve the problem that the subclass inherits the base class and meanwhile the base class is a template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 
 template <typename Child>
 struct Base
 {
     void interface()
     {
         static_cast<Child*>(this)->implementation();
     }
 };
 
 template<typename T,
     template<class T> class Base
 >
 struct Derived : Base<Derived >
 {
     void implementation(T t=0)
     {
          t = 0;
         cerr << "Derived implementation----" << t;
     }
 };



 int main()
 {
     Derived<int,Base<Derived>> d; //Base class as a template parameter is must  
     d.interface();  // Prints "Derived implementation"
 
     return 0;
 }
```

I hope `Derived` class inherits from a template parameter `Base` class,meanwhile hope the instance of  `Base` class depend on `Derived` class, the `Derived` class have another template  parameter `T`,I have tried many ways but can't solve it .

`Base class as a template parameter is must`

I have simplified the source code, but these conditions I describe are necessary.

Now I hope that under these conditions I describe, I can call the `interface()` sucessfully

Does anyone know where the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Your question should be more descriptive about the problem, you only mention what you are trying to achieve and that there is *some* problem, but you don't explain what it is.

Comment: What is your final goal? It looks like you are looking for (pure) virtual methods?

Comment: The only problem I see is that `implementation` expects one argument, but you are calling it without argument. Please explain what exactly is not working with the code you are showing.

Comment: so sorry, I've updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
template<typename T, 
        template <typename> typename Base>
struct Derived : Base<Derived<T, Base>>
{
    void implementation(T t=0)
    {
        t = 0;
        cerr << "Derived implementation----" << t;
    }
};

Derived<int, Base> d;
d.interface();  // Prints "Derived implementation"
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/heboP5K7v)

Comment: very thanks for your answer, Your answer basically solved the problem, and I would like to ask, what should I do if I want to run on gcc 4.8.1?

Comment: @asele https://godbolt.org/z/jPP6nocE4 Little changes for older compiler.

Comment: very thanks . My problem is completely solved.

Comment: Glad it helps. Would you mind considering accepting my ans?

Comment: Of course,But I don't have enough reputation ,so I can`t vote, I'm very sorry for that, I'll come to vote when I have enough reputation.